# How to restore content from quit migration?

Tags: macbook-pro, restore, migration

I bought a new MacBook Pro and began working on it. I saved all my preferences, had some files on here, etc. My old MacBook has USB ports that don't work so I can't transfer files via Time Machine. Apple's site says that WiFi is the fastest way to transfer (which is apparently inaccurate) so I did that overnight. I woke up to find that I still had 44 hours left, and I need to work so I quit both. Old Mac is fine. New Mac is restored.

When I used Migration Assistant it said that it would save the new Mac's data in a folder somewhere. That is what I'm hoping to be able to find and restore settings. Does anyone know where that folder is and how to do that or am I out of luck and starting over?

Answer (score 1):

Several follow-up questions to help answer your question.

1. Do you have a Time Machine backup of the old MacBook?
2. When you say "New Mac is restored", what do you mean? Can you see/use the new User account from the login page? If you can, then you should be able to see the data for your account, as it wouldn't be possible to log in otherwise.
3. The folder might be under /Users possibly in a folder called something like "Deleted Users". From the Finder, select "Go > Go To Folder", type in "/Users/" and press enter and see if your files are there.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response!

1. Yes but not for a while as the USB has been broken for some time.
2. Not sure the correct term but the new Mac is basically up and running. All is fine except all my files are gone. I had been working on it for a couple weeks so I had Pages data, Mail logins, and some files on here that are all gone. The computer is essentially restored to the original settings.
3. I will check this out now!

Comment: YES! It's there! THANK YOU! Do you know if there is a way to reinstall this user so that all my logins and settings (most specifically Mail settings) are restored? Or am I just getting access to the files?

Comment: I found this: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22002?locale=en_US but I'm lost at #2. I only see a folder with my name on it not my name with .dmg

Comment: Step 2 takes the .DMG file and creates a folder. So, basically, that step has already been done for you. Just continue with Step 3.

Comment: I get this notice when I do that: “michelledavella” can’t be modified or deleted because it’s required by macOS.

Comment: If I don't hold Option down I can drag it but I'm not sure if that's ok

Comment: Oops, hold on, reset.

In /Users, do you have a folder called Deleted Users? If not, then the michelledavella folder *is* the account you've been using before trying to restore data. If so, you need to look in there to then follow the Apple instructions.

Comment: Yes, the folder in deleted users is called michelledavella

Comment: When I try to drag it by using the command button and the little icon at the top I get this: “michelledavella” can’t be modified or deleted because it’s required by macOS.

Comment: ok, that's because you already have a folder with that name. try renaming the one in Deleted Users to just "michelle" and then follow the Apple instructions.

Comment: @MichelleD'Avella if you ever come back around here, please mark this answer as accepted! That, and only that, is THE way to say merci on SE sites ...